# Агрегаты в elasticsearch против агрегирующих функций в реляционных бд

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Наткнулся в одном видео на пример, когда количество товаров в категориях для меню доставалось из elasticsearch:

```
'aggs' => [
    'group_by_category' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'categories'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Зачем здесь эластик, если можно обойтись функцией count и group by в Mysql или postgres.

Comment: Так а в ролике в целом речь про что была?

Comment: ды это полноценный курс. Вопрос в том, что все таки быстрее, эластик или бд?

Comment: Ну это скорее демонстрация возможностей, а не то, что прям эластик в данном случае лучше или быстрее. Понятно, что все зависит от задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко, то ElasticSearch строит агрегации гораздо быстрее MySQL. И чем больше данных, тем эта разница более существенна.

Я замерил время выполнения запросов на боевом сервере.

**Параметры сервера**

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, RAM 30Mb, SSD
MySQL 5.6, количество записей в таблице - 250258
ElasticSearch 2.4, документов столько же.

MySQL

```
select brand_id, count(*) from product group by brand_id
```

ElasticSearch

```
time curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/product/_search?pretty=true" -d '{"size": 0,"aggs": {"group_by_brand": {"terms": {"field": "brand.id"}}}}'
```

**Время выполнения**

MySQL - 55...76мс, среднее 65.5мс

ElasticSearch - 19...24мс, среднее 21.5мс

Если бы данных было более 1 млн., то разница была бы существеннее.

---

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что выбрать зависит от задачи. Если вам требуется подсчитать количество товаров в категориях меню и их не слишком много (< 100), то можно смело использовать MySQL. 
А если вам нужно построить фильтры для параметрического поиска, где для каждого значения фильтра отображается количество товаров, то следует использовать только ElasticSearch.

Хорошая статья в тему: [Use the index, JSON! Aggregation performance](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2016/use-index-json-aggregation-performance-elastic-mysql-mongodb/)